# Istio error: invalid host header when trying to access using a FQDN

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

When I'm accessing istio endpoint using a FQDN it's showing this error whilst accessing just using IP is working fine.

I tried to see if there's any issues with gateway or virtual service but they look fine otherwise SSL termination wouldn't have worked with IP

Comment: checking access logs of ingress-gateway pod and application pod will give a clue on the issue.